# After entering a string of text in the entry, use tkinter.place

Tags: python, tkinter

After entering a string of text in the entry, using tkinter.place _forget () to hide the input box, the text in the input box is cleared after it is displayed. Is there any good way to keep the text in the input box?

Comment: So why don't use `insert()` to insert the previous text when you show the entry?

Comment: `place_forget` won't clear the data in a widget. All it does is hide a widget. The widget still exists, and still contains the same data. Can you please provide a [mcve] that you think shows that the data is being cleared?